# How do I create an Iterator class to iterate over a 2d array pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, iterator

I am trying to build an iterator class in c++ for a class that has a 2d array of size 8x8 as its main data member. I want to iterate over the 2d array column wise.

I am trying to think about this in terms of how a vector iterator class is written.

How should I go about creating this Iterator class?
Would the constructor need to accept a double pointer (**obj) ? Assuming I do that, how would I perform increments while overloading the ++ operator for the double pointer?

This is what I have

```
class Iterator
{
public:
    Iterator(Board **obj)
    {
        ptr = obj;
    }
    Iterator& operator++()
    {
        ptr++;
    }

private:
    Board **ptr;
};
```

Comment: Cheat like hell. C++ heavily favours row-major order, so If the data is to be primarily accessed in column major order, rotate the data 90 degrees so that rows and columns are swapped and provide an index operator that presents the data in the user's expected order for the rare times they need to display it with the correct coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

First off, your given implementation is NOT correct. When you increment your pointer, you're incrementing it by one Board, not one position in the board. That's not at all what you want.

If you're going to implement iterators properly, you need to start with the containing class -- assuming you're actually talking about iterators so you can do something like:

for (int i: myBoard) {
}

and the compiler knows what to do.

```
class Board {
public:
    class ForwardIterator { ... };
    class ReverseIterator { ... };

    ForwardIterator begin() { ... }
    ForwardIterator end() { ... }.   // Should return one position past the end
    ReverseIterator rbegin() { ... }
    ReverseIterator rend() { ... }.  // One position before beginning

};
```

That's just a start. You also need const versions. You can probably clean this up with the use of templates, but you start to see -- it's not necessarily trivial.

Under the hood, the iterator can work however you want it to work. You can keep an `int row, col` for instance, and just move them accordingly. In the most simplest form, that's what I would do.

You also need operator= and operator!= so that you can compare iterators to detect past-beginning or past-ending.

Don't forget to also implement:

```
int & operator*() { return board[row][col]; }
```

A complete answer, done properly, is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow. This isn't a bad link: https://internalpointers.com/post/writing-custom-iterators-modern-cpp. But a google for "writing iterators c++" will yield a variety of useful links for the nitty gritty details.